# tail like console for the file that is periodically overwritten

Tags: linux, bash

Let's assume that I have a process that dumps remote console periodically to some temporary file with static name.

So the temporary file is overwritten every let's say 5 seconds with some content that changes over time (so it's incremental content).

Any option I could get tail -f like console watching the temporary file?

If I use tail -F then I'm getting the whole content of file every time new content is written to temporary file.

Comment: Using a pipe file may help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it - you want to watch the file content, but getting the file content with tail is not what you want - can you elaborate a bit more, so I understand what you want in the end - what is your expected output when watching the file - you want like always the last 20 lines of it, or what? Thanks m8

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) for this, something like

```
watch -n 1 cat temporary_file_with_static_name
```

`-n 1` means it'll refresh every second. I'm not using 5 seconds because when I tried it, a slight delay added up over time, which, over a few minutes, would make it out of sync with your file. I tested it with this, which syncs up with `date` before starting `watch`:

```
until [[ $(date "+%N") == 00* ]]; do true; done; watch -n1 date -Ins
```